# Overlapping tables from grid.arrange in gridExtra

Tags: r, latex, knitr, gridextra

I'm trying to build an automated report that will have three charts right underneath each other without margin space between each other.

I've mocked up my problem with the following Rmd script

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(gridExtra)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
car_tbl <- tableGrob(mtcars[1:10,])
grid.arrange(car_tbl, car_tbl, car_tbl)
```
````

You can see how the tables overlap each other.  There seems like there are actually a few issues comprising my problem.

1. How do I use the options of tableGrob and grid.arrange to keep the tables from overlapping.
2. How do I make sure nothing is cut off?  In other words, how do I set the graphic to take the whole page if I need it too?
3. How can I re-actively shrink the text of the plot to fit on one page?
4. How can I set the size of the page to whatever size I want?  Are there options set the knitr document to print to a pdf page of any size I want? Perhaps poster size if I need it to?

Comment: have you checked this FAQ? https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki#problems-with-gridtable

Comment: btw, when you say 3 charts right underneath each other, do you mean the 3 tables? Would it be easier to combine the tables into 1? Do they have the same number of columns? What size do they have (ie will they fit in a standard a4 page with a legible font size?)

Comment: yes. I have seen the wiki and it has been helpful so far but there are so many setting from the paper size to the font size that I am a little overwhelmed from all the other options outside of gridExtra.  Love the package btw.

Comment: The tables should all have the same number of columns but are essentially different.  I guess if the data could be "faceted" into three tables that would be ideal.  So that it shows the same variables for columns and rows with another variable for the facets.  I woud like to print to A3 or A2 ideally but have the control to do more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different angles to approach your question. Here's a working example with three tables fitting in one chunk placed on a pdf of size A2.

````
---
output: pdf_document
geometry: paper=a2paper
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(gridExtra)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.height=10}
car_tbl <- tableGrob(mtcars[1:10,])
grid.arrange(car_tbl, car_tbl, car_tbl)
```
````

---

To address your questions specifically,

```
1. How do I use the options of tableGrob and grid.arrange to keep the tables from overlapping.
```

Their overlap had more to do with the default fig.height set by knitr.

```
2. How do I make sure nothing is cut off? In other words, how do I set the graphic to take the whole page if I need it too?
```

Make sure the figure height and page are big enough for the table.

```
3. How can I re-actively shrink the text of the plot to fit on one page?
```

It's not trivial, but I guess it could be done. I doubt it's a good idea though (for typographical reasons): typically the font size should be set, and if the table doesn't fit, it should be split into several pages (there's an example in a link I provided).

```
3. How can I set the size of the page to whatever size I want? Are there options set the knitr document to print to a pdf page of any size I want? Perhaps poster size if I need it to?
```

It's a latex question, which in the context of Rmd documents means that you could pass these layout options to latex via rmarkdown and pandoc, typically as options for the geometry package.

Comment: Thanks!  I was nervous to keep playing with figure height options because I thought this might be the real reason.